# How to optimize mongo indices for groupby operations in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

In mongo I have an aggregation pipeline where I'm attempting to summarize information about all timeseries data in a collection of millions of records. The timeseries data can be grouped a composite identifier ("identifier1" & "identifier2"). The goal is to show the first and last timestamp for records in each group.

Here is my working query:

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "identifier1": "$identifier1",
        "identifier2": "$identifier2"
      },
      "min_timestamp": {
        "$min": "$timestamp"
      },
      "max_timestamp": {
        "$max": "$timestamp"
      }
    }
  },
])
```

While it works, it does not appear to be efficient. In atlas, the query monitor for this query shows "keys examined" = 0. The query can take anywhere from 5 seconds to 30 seconds depending on the load on the server. I have 2 indexes on the collection currently. One just on timestamp descending, and then this unique index:

```
{
    "identifier1" : 1.0,
    "identifier2" : 1.0,
    "timestamp" : 1.0
}
```

What index do I need so that the group operator can utilize it for better performance?

Comment: One quick clarification, when you refer to it as timeseries data, you're just referring to what the data logically represents to the application/business, but the collection in MongoDB is a regular one as opposed to a time series collection? Actually one other thing - how many source documents typically get collapsed into each group?

Comment: Ah, good distinction. Just a regular collection with time series type data in it. Each group will have a range of hundreds to low-tens-of-thousands in them.

Comment: From what I've been reading, it seems the group operator doesn't use indices. Hence the full table scan that appears to be going on. Maybe I just need to change the structure of the data and use parent objects to pre-group data by the identifiers in a child array. I was hoping to avoid doing that.